# Combine two tables into one result set with Laravel Eloquent. merge/append/join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an `expenses` and `expense_splits` table.
I'd like to combine both into one result set. Every `expense_splits` should have added attributes from the expense it belongs to. It seems like there is a lot of ways to go about this but none seem just right.

For example, a leftjoin like this almost works for me but it deletes all my expenses id #s and only keeps `expense_splits`.

```
$expenses = DB::table('expenses')
            -leftJoin('expense_splits', 'expenses.id', '=', 'expense_splits.expense_id')
            ->get();
```

Ideally, I need all attributes from my expense table to show in my `expense_splits` result. Unless of course attributes are the same on both tables, then show `expense_splits` attribute (which a jelftjoin does for me..but it deletes my `expenses.id`).

I can also merge/push my two collections. This is a quick way to show them within one result set. However, I'm not sure how to add expense attributes to each `expense_splits`. I need my `expense_splits` to be treated as a regular expense (and if an expense has splits I can't have it shown..but i'll worry about that later). There will never be a time where I don't need this anywhere on my app.

```
$splits = ExpenseSplit::all();
$expenses = Expense::all();

$expenses = $expenses->merge($splits);
```

I can also append to my `ExpenseSplits` result, but, honestly, idk where to place this or if it even makes sense. I'd need it placed somewhere where it's called everytime I call `Expense::all()` and I can't copy & paste all over the app.

```
$expense_split = ExpenseSplit::find(34);
$expense_split->receipt = $expense_split->expense->receipt;
$expense_split->receipt_html = $expense_split->expense->receipt_html;
$expense_split->check_id = $expense_split->expense->check_id;
```

What is the best place to place this code so it's avaliable as simply as `Expense::all()` and these splits from my `expense_splits` table will be included. And of course, how do I go about doing this in the first place. It seems there's a lot of ways to get this done.

Thanks, Patryk

Database schema:
EXPENSES TABLE: (SIMPLIFIED)
| id  | expense_date | amount  | project_id | receipt | paid_by | check_id

EXPENSE_SPLITS TABLE: (SIMPLIFIED)
| id  | expnese_id | amount  | project_id |

Comment: Can you post your DB Schema? this sounds like it can be solved with proper use of Eloquent relationships (instead of these left join / join queries).

Comment: Thant would be great! I've added it above. What I'm looking for in the end is to append `expense_splits` into my `expenses` in views. So when I pull up my expenses table(in views, not a sql table i mean), the splits are inlcluded as well together with the details from the parent expense.

Comment: Did you use Laravel database migration files to create the tables ? and have you got the corresponding Models for each table ?

Comment: Yes. $expnese_split->belongsTo('App\Expense')
 AND $expense->hasMany('App\ExpenseSplit')

Comment: Check out my comment, you should be able to use Eloquent to query all the data.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure how you've done your models but this is an example of what it should look like:

```
class Expenses extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'expenses';

    public function splitExpenses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ExpenseSplits');
    }
}

class ExpenseSplits extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'expense_splits';

    public function expenses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Expenses');
    }
}


$expenses = Expenses::where('id', 1)->with('splitExpenses')->get();
```

So essentially your $expenses should have all the split expense objects if one exists..

Read up on:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

There is no need to use any DB::table since you're using Eloquent. It takes care of everything for you if you set up the relationships correctly.